# JavaScript open brace in the same line

Tags: javascript

I remember there is a convention/recommendation to put opening brace in the same line, because of the way JavaScript adds a semicolon or something.

```
//OK
function blah(){
};

//Probably not OK
function blah() 
{
};
```

But I don't find a relevant source to confirm/deny this.

Is this true? Or just a myth?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905238/opening-curly-bracket-brace-position-on-code

Comment: @miccet I think(heard/believe) in javascript it is not just a matter of style. That's what I'm asking. That question is in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This post on Elegant Code](http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/12/basic-javascript-part-6-automatic-semicolon-insertion/) gives some explanation of automatic semicolon insertion, but in regard to returning objects, not declaring functions.

Answer (score 25):

The issue you are thinking of is for `return` statements.

```
return {
  value: 'test'
}
```

Works fine, but the following does not:

```
return
{
  value: 'test'
}
```

JavaScript adds a semicolon after `return` turning the above into:

```
return;
{
  value: 'test'
}
```

Comment: It's a pity: just because of this issue with return statements, most JS code is using same-line-opening-braces everywhere. Meh.

Comment: @lorancou: Hey!  I like putting my open braces on the same line :-P

Comment: That's obviously because JS corrupted you ;)

Comment: @lorancou: Actually Java corrupted me (that was my 1st language) :-P

Answer (score 6):

Douglas Crockford gives a reason for choosing the K&R style [1]:

"I always use the K&R style, putting the { at the end of a line instead of the front, because it avoids a horrible design blunder in JavaScript's return statement.

The blunder he is referring to is how JavaScript handles the return statement differently in the following two scenarios:

```
return {
   'status': 'ok'
};
```

... and:

```
return 
{
   'status': 'ok'
};
```

The first one will return an object with a status property, while the latter will return undefined because of semicolon insertion."

[1] Douglas Crockford: JavaScript: The Good Parts: Style (p. 96)

Answer (score 5):

The [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden) has a chapter about [automatic semicolon insertion](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#semicolon). It gives good examples when semicolons are added automatically:

> JavaScript is not a semicolon-less
>   language, it in fact needs the
>   semicolons in order to understand the
>   source code. Therefore the JavaScript
>   parser automatically inserts them
>   whenever it encounters a parse error
>   due to a missing semicolon.

In your example JavaScript wouldn't encounter an error due to a missing semicolon though.

Answer (score 3):

There is no issue with declaring functions, but you can get into trouble when returning objects:

```
function foo()
{ // this is OK

    return
    { // this is BAD!
        name: "bletch"
    };
    // actually returns undefined!
}
```

A semi-colon is automatically inserted after the return statement, and that will break your code.

Answer (score -1):

It's a myth. `function blah()` is always required to be followed by a expression block, so makes no difference which style you use. The first style is simply the most widely used form.