# jQuery autocomplete results box not displaying for JSON stream converted to `label` & `value`

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I had jQuery autocomplete working with the autocomplete search results box showing at the appropriate location. That was for server side search support with the following client side js:

```
$("#someSearchTermInputBox").autocomplete(
{
    minLength: 2,
    source: "/searchThatReturnsStringListOfResults"
});
```

In this case, the server sends back to the client the following information (the following via Chrome debugger):

```
["Alice","Bob","Calvin","Dirk","Elvin","Fancy","Greg","Harry","Issey","Jack"]
```

The corresponding input text box is:

```
<input id="someSearchTermInputBox" name="someSearchTermInputBox"  placeholder="Search for people, events and places" type="search"
```

Because I need more functionality, I changed my search to return a JSON that looks like this:

> [{"firstname":"Alice","lastname":"Anonymous","dateOfBirth":"1980-01-01","phone":"001-100-200-3001","email":"alice.anonymous@gmail.com"},{"firstname":"Bob","lastname":"Anonymous","dateOfBirth":"1987-02-07","phone":"001-100-200-3002","email":"bob.anonymous@gmail.com"},{"firstname":"Calvin","lastname":"Anonymous","dateOfBirth":"1984-02-09","phone":"001-100-200-3003","email":"calvin.anonymous@gmail.com"},{"firstname":"Dirk","lastname":"Anonymous","dateOfBirth":"1982-05-01","phone":"001-100-200-3004","email":"dirk.anonymous@gmail.com"},{"firstname":"Elvin","lastname":"Anonymous","dateOfBirth":"1980-07-05","phone":"001-100-200-3005","email":"elvin.anonymous@gmail.com"},{"firstname":"Fancy","lastname":"Anonymous","dateOfBirth":"1990-02-01","phone":"001-100-200-3006","email":"fancy.anonymous@gmail.com"},{"firstname":"Greg","lastname":"Anonymous","dateOfBirth":"1984-01-09","phone":"001-100-200-3007","email":"greg.anonymous@gmail.com"},{"firstname":"Harry","lastname":"Anonymous","dateOfBirth":"1989-11-10","phone":"001-100-200-3008","email":"harry.anonymous@gmail.com"},{"firstname":"Issey","lastname":"Anonymous","dateOfBirth":"1950-01-01","phone":"001-100-200-3009","email":"issey.anonymous@gmail.com"},{"firstname":"Jack","lastname":"Anonymous","dateOfBirth":"1970-10-01","phone":"001-100-200-3010","email":"jack.anonymous@gmail.com"}]

And to split the results to be jQuery autocomplete compatible, I changed my client side js to this to map the incoming JSON to `label` and `value` or `id` (tried both `id` and `label`):

```
$("someSearchTermInputBox").autocomplete(
    {
    minLength: 2,
    source: function (request, response)
    {
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/searchThatReturnsJSON",
        data: {term: request.term},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {
        // alert (JSON.stringify (data)); <-- shows up correctly
        // console.log (data);
        response ($.map(data, function (item)
             {
                 console.log (item.firstname);
                 return
                 { id: item.firstname; value: item.lastname };
             }));
        }
    });
},
});
```

My header is as follows (unchanged from the previous working version):

```
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" > </script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js" > </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css" />
```

and now, my autocomplete box does not show up (it is not empty--it does not show up at all(I can see the Ajax interaction happening with the server on the debugger and on the server)). I am doing this in Chrome, so I fired up the debugger and I see the JSON correctly returned from the server. What HTML/CSS magic do I need to make sure my search results show up?

Where can I find the documentation on jQuery's web site (the jQuery autocomplete main website--the documentation does not talk about label or value, and certainly doesn't talk about the correct div elements to manipulate).

BTW, for the correct way to return a tuple into the `response` in the `map` call, is the delimiter a comma or a semicolon? Chrome gives me an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` which only went away when I changed the delimiter in the tuple returned to a semicolon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow. I am just open mouthed in awe of the incredible syntax of JS. Anyway, the key issue was the use of the `return` statement `{..}` brackets. For a JS noob like me, this was countless hours down the drain trying to grasp any logic behind JS syntax and the use of K&R style brackets in a `return` statement (which I loathe as I am an Allman brackets guy).

Anyway, the code that got it to work finally was

```
$(document).ready (function ()
{
    $("someSearchTermInputBox").autocomplete(
    {
    minLength: 2,
    source: function (request, response)
    {
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/search",
        data: {term: request.term},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonDataReceivedFromServer)
        {
        //alert (JSON.stringify (jsonDataReceivedFromServer));
        // console.log (jsonDataReceivedFromServer);
        response ($.map(jsonDataReceivedFromServer, function (item)
            {
            console.log (item.firstname);
                            // NOTE: BRACKET START IN THE SAME LINE AS RETURN IN 
                            //       THE FOLLOWING LINE
            return {
                id: item.firstname, value: item.lastname };
            }));
        }
      });
     },
   });
});
```

Anyway, for folks who are Allman-indenters, I suggest using the following syntax which is  Allman indentation friendly:

```
var someTuple = 
  {
      value: item.firstname,
      id:    item.lastname
  };
return someTuple;
```

A special shout out to the SO posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107510/javascript-open-brace-in-the-same-line) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745743/automatic-semicolon-insertion-return-statements). And a better post on the matter and curated (?) opinions [here](http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/).

I hope this helps someone because I expect more people to run into this issue.

Comment: Note: I changed the URL in between, the URL should not have any impact on the solution. The minLength order, or spaces before or after function names, in between parameter names, etc. did not matter.