# JavaScript syntax rules

Tags: javascript

```js
function A() {
  return {
    'name': "a"
  };
}

function B() {
  return 
  {
    'name': "b"
  };
}

console.log(A());
console.log(B());
```

On my browser this code generates the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Browser Google Chrome:

> Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)

As far as I know JavaScript accepts an end statement after the return statement.

What makes the first `return` an **end statement** but not the second?

Comment: Which browser ?

Comment: Are you probably referring to this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5107577/10955263

Comment: Please double check that the example produces the same error you see?

Comment: I'm sorry but the snippet was edited by someone else. Fixed now.

Comment: no error on codepen [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLNQpO?editors=1111)

Comment: Yep. Now it fails in Chrome and in the snippet.

Comment: The code was reedited to the original script.

Comment: comment by 04FS is on the point - please take a look at his link.

Comment: @04FS Thank you, it is indeed a duplicate. I flagged it. Cheers.
Edit: phuzi yes.

Comment: reproduced in chromium